# How to change the texture of a content that has been loaded already?

Tags: c#, xna

I got a menu in my game with buttons to select the level, except for the first level button, all the other buttons use a gray texture, as they are "locked". So when you beat the level 1 for example, it returns to the level selecting menu and the level 2 is unlocked, but i want it to use a different texture when it's unlocked, so i tried to add this in my Update method in the main game class but it still using the gray texture:

```
            if (level2.Unlocked == true)
            {
                level2Button = Content.Load<Texture2D>("GUI\\level2");
            }
            level2Button.Update(gameTime);
```

Comment: Do you have a class for your buttons? Does it have a property that represents which texture should be used? What is level2Button?

Comment: As Feux's fine answer below, creating or updating a new texture during the draw loop is `slow` because the data has to be transferred from the CPU to the GPU. The CPU-to-GPU memory bus is incredibility slow compared to accessing data already uploaded/created on the GPU.  Offtopic but the only time I can think of where it is OK to update a texture during the game-loop is using render targets but then again that all happens on the GPU anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Fuex and roxik0, i used both suggestions to solve it. I created two texture variables and in my button class i added a method to update the textures:

```
    public void UpdateTexture(Texture2D texture)
    {
        this.texture = texture;
    }
```

This way before it draws the button it checks if the level is unlocked and update it to use the proper textures:

```
 if (level2.Unlocked)
                {
                    level2button.UpdateTexture(level2buttonNormal);
                }
level2button.Draw(spriteBatch);
```

Comment: Was it really necessary to post this amalgamated answer?

Answer (score 2):

You have to have 2 textures and select proper on "draw" stage. There is no other options.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: My answer provide sollution:
2 textures and choosing on draw stage.

Answer (score 2):

I really recommend you not to load it in the update method, it isn't a good practice. The side effects can produce a frame rate drop (lag) and other unwanted behavior. So my advice is to load it in the *LoadContent* method:

```
protected override void LoadContent( ) {
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

    //...
    level2ButtonUnlocked = Content.Load<Texture2D>("GUI\\level2");
}
```

And then in the *Update* method assign it:

```
protected override void Update( GameTime gameTime ) {
    if (level2.Unlocked == true){
        level2Button = level2ButtonUnlocked; 
    }
}
```

So this is one of the approaches. I'd use a cleaner and smarter one, like a `Dictionary<string, Texture2D>` or a `List<Level>` where *Level* contains a *Texture* property and an *IsLocked* field and every index represents the number of the level like:

```
class Level {
   public Texture2D Texture {
      get {
         if( IsLocked )
            return lockedTexture;

         return unlockedTexture;
      }   
   }

   public bool IsLocked = true;
   private Texture2D lockedTexture, unlockedTexture;

   public LoadContent( ContentManager content, string lockedPath, string unlockedPath ){
       lockedTexture = content.Load<Texture2D>( lockedPath );
       unlockedTexture = content.Load<Texture2D>( unlockedPath );
   }
}
```